# How to have two Three-JS Objects run and animate at the same time?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've created two 3JS objects and scenes for learning purposes. Both housed in separate PHP files (not in the jsfiddle). However, I can't figure out why by adding a second object the first object stops animating and doesn't run anymore? How can I go about figuring out why my objects are canceling one another out and how to create two different or more multiple threejs items that animate at the same time?

//GRID OBJ is the first object, and the second is //BALL
When I remove the second script calling for 3js ball the grid will animate, when the ball is added the grid stops animating and only the ball animates.

http://jsfiddle.net/tdqh4jno/

```js
//GRID OBJ
var container = document.getElementById('grid')

var vertexHeight = 90,
  planeDefinition = 25,
  planeSize = 900,
  totalObjects = 1,
  background = "#002135",
  meshColor = "#ff3057";

var camera2 = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 110, 1, 5)
camera2.position.y = 500;

var scene2 = new THREE.Scene();
scene2.background = new THREE.Color( 0x08080c);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true});
renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );

var planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(planeSize, planeSize, planeDefinition, planeDefinition);

var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: meshColor,
  wireframe: true
}));
plane.rotation.x -= Math.PI * .5;

scene2.add(plane);

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(background, 1);
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

function updatePlane() {
  for (var i = 0; i < planeGeo.vertices.length; i++) {
    planeGeo.vertices[i].z += Math.random() * vertexHeight;
    planeGeo.vertices[i]._myZ = planeGeo.vertices[i].z
  }

};

var count = 0

function renderGrid() {
  var gridSpeed = 0.4;
  var gridInterlop = -0.4;
  var gridWaveSpeed = 0.003;  
  var gridWaveHeight = 0.00003;

  requestAnimationFrame(renderGrid);

  for (var i = 0; i < planeGeo.vertices.length; i++) {
    var z = +planeGeo.vertices[i].z;
    planeGeo.vertices[i].z = Math.sin(( i + count * gridWaveHeight)) * (planeGeo.vertices[i]._myZ - (planeGeo.vertices[i]._myZ * gridWaveSpeed))
    plane.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
    count += gridInterlop
  }

  renderer.render(scene2, camera2);

}

updatePlane();
renderGrid();


//BALL ITEM
 var camera2 = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(100, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.autoClear = false;
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  var sceneTop = new THREE.Scene(); // initialising the scene
  sceneTop.background = new THREE.Color( 0x08080c);


  var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
  spotLight.position.set(100,100,100);
  spotLight.castShadow = false;
  sceneTop.add(spotLight);

  function Mat(){
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color      : new THREE.Color(0xff3266),
      emissive   : new THREE.Color(0x08080c),
      specular   : new THREE.Color(0x08080c),

      shininess  : 0,
      wireframe  : true,
      transparent: 0.5,
      opacity    : 0.55
    });
    return material;
  }

  var geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(45 , 1);
  var obj = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, Mat());


  sceneTop.add(obj);

  camera2.position.z = 90;

  function myrender(){
    renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );

    obj.rotation.x += 0.0004;
    obj.rotation.y += 0.0006;
    obj.rotation.z += Math.random() * 0.0005;
    renderer.render(sceneTop, camera2);
    requestAnimationFrame(myrender);
  }



  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, true);

  function onWindowResize() {
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera2.updateProjectionMatrix();
};


    myrender();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/99/three.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You create 2 [`THREE.WebGLRenderer`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer) objects, but both assigned to the variable `renderer`. This breaks down the animation of the first (grid) object in the function `renderGrid`.

In your code are created 2 different scenes referenced by 2 different variables (`sceneTop`, `scene2`). Create 2 different render objects, referenced by 2 different variables (`renderer`, `renderer2`), too:

```js
var scene2 = new THREE.Scene();
scene2.background = new THREE.Color( 0x08080c);
var renderer2 = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true});
renderer2.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );

// [...]

renderer2.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer2.setClearColor(background, 1);
container.appendChild(renderer2.domElement);

function renderGrid() {

    // [...]

    renderer2.render(scene2, camera2);
}
```

In the following you have to respect, that `renderer` corresponds to `camera` respectively `sceneTop`, but `renderer2` corresponds to `scene2` and `camera2`:

```
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(100, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

[...]

camera.position.z = 90;

function myrender(){

    // [...]    

    renderer.render(sceneTop, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(myrender);
}
```

See the example, where I applied the suggested changes to your original code:

```js
//GRID OBJ
var container = document.getElementById('grid')

var vertexHeight = 90,
  planeDefinition = 25,
  planeSize = 900,
  totalObjects = 1,
  background = "#002135",
  meshColor = "#ff3057";

var camera2 = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 110, 1, 5)
camera2.position.y = 500;

var scene2 = new THREE.Scene();
scene2.background = new THREE.Color( 0x08080c);
var renderer2 = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true});
renderer2.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );

var planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(planeSize, planeSize, planeDefinition, planeDefinition);

var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: meshColor,
  wireframe: true
}));
plane.rotation.x -= Math.PI * .5;

scene2.add(plane);

renderer2.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer2.setClearColor(background, 1);
container.appendChild(renderer2.domElement);

function updatePlane() {
  for (var i = 0; i < planeGeo.vertices.length; i++) {
    planeGeo.vertices[i].z += Math.random() * vertexHeight;
    planeGeo.vertices[i]._myZ = planeGeo.vertices[i].z
  }

};

var count = 0

function renderGrid() {
  var gridSpeed = 0.4;
  var gridInterlop = -0.4;
  var gridWaveSpeed = 0.003;  
  var gridWaveHeight = 0.00003;

  requestAnimationFrame(renderGrid);

  for (var i = 0; i < planeGeo.vertices.length; i++) {
    var z = +planeGeo.vertices[i].z;
    planeGeo.vertices[i].z = Math.sin(( i + count * gridWaveHeight)) * (planeGeo.vertices[i]._myZ - (planeGeo.vertices[i]._myZ * gridWaveSpeed))
    plane.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
    count += gridInterlop
  }

  renderer2.render(scene2, camera2);
}

updatePlane();
renderGrid();


//BALL ITEM
 var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(100, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
  
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.autoClear = false;
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  var sceneTop = new THREE.Scene(); // initialising the scene
  sceneTop.background = new THREE.Color( 0x08080c);


  var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
  spotLight.position.set(100,100,100);
  spotLight.castShadow = false;
  sceneTop.add(spotLight);

  function Mat(){
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color      : new THREE.Color(0xff3266),
      emissive   : new THREE.Color(0x08080c),
      specular   : new THREE.Color(0x08080c),

      shininess  : 0,
      wireframe  : true,
      transparent: 0.5,
      opacity    : 0.55
    });
    return material;
  }

  var geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(45 , 1);
  var obj = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, Mat());

  sceneTop.add(obj);

  camera.position.z = 90;

  function myrender(){
    renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );

    obj.rotation.x += 0.0004;
    obj.rotation.y += 0.0006;
    obj.rotation.z += Math.random() * 0.0005;
    renderer.render(sceneTop, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(myrender);
  }

  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, true);

  function onWindowResize() {
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer2.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight; 
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    camera2.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight; 
    camera2.updateProjectionMatrix();
};

myrender();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/99/three.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid"></div>
```

---

Alternatively both scenes can be rendered to different parts of the viewport.

Create 1 [`THREE.WebGLRenderer`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer), with the [`.autoClear`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.autoClear) property set to `false`:

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true, preserveDrawingBuffer: true});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );
renderer.autoClear = false;
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

Render both scenes 2 different parts of the viewport. The viewport rectangle can be changed by [.setViewport](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.setViewport):

```
function myrender(){

    // [...]

    renderer.setViewport(0,0,window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.clear();

    renderer.setViewport(window.innerWidth/2,0,window.innerWidth/2, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.render(sceneTop, camera, 0, false);

    renderer.setViewport(0,0,window.innerWidth/2, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.render(scene2, camera2, 0, false);

    requestAnimationFrame(myrender);
}
```

Ensure that the [.background](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/scenes/Scene.background) property is only set for the [THREE.Scene](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/scenes/Scene) which is rendered first.

See the example:

```js
//GRID OBJ
var container = document.getElementById('grid')

var vertexHeight = 90,
  planeDefinition = 25,
  planeSize = 900,
  totalObjects = 1,
  background = "#002135",
  meshColor = "#ff3057";

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true, preserveDrawingBuffer: true});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );
renderer.autoClear = false;
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var camera2 = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 110, window.innerWidth/2/window.innerHeight, 5)
camera2.position.y = 500;

var scene2 = new THREE.Scene();

var planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(planeSize, planeSize, planeDefinition, planeDefinition);

var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: meshColor,
  wireframe: true
}));
plane.rotation.x -= Math.PI * .5;

scene2.add(plane);


function updatePlane() {
  for (var i = 0; i < planeGeo.vertices.length; i++) {
    planeGeo.vertices[i].z += Math.random() * vertexHeight;
    planeGeo.vertices[i]._myZ = planeGeo.vertices[i].z
  }

};

var count = 0

updatePlane();

//BALL ITEM
 var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(100, window.innerWidth/2/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

  var sceneTop = new THREE.Scene(); // initialising the scene
  sceneTop.background = new THREE.Color( 0x08080c);

  var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
  spotLight.position.set(100,100,100);
  spotLight.castShadow = false;
  sceneTop.add(spotLight);

  function Mat(){
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color      : new THREE.Color(0xff3266),
      emissive   : new THREE.Color(0x08080c),
      specular   : new THREE.Color(0x08080c),

      shininess  : 0,
      wireframe  : true,
      transparent: 0.5,
      opacity    : 0.55
    });
    return material;
  }

  var geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(45 , 1);
  var obj = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, Mat());

  sceneTop.add(obj);

  camera.position.z = 90;

  function myrender(){
    var gridSpeed = 0.4;
    var gridInterlop = -0.4;
    var gridWaveSpeed = 0.003;  
    var gridWaveHeight = 0.00003;
    for (var i = 0; i < planeGeo.vertices.length; i++) {
      var z = +planeGeo.vertices[i].z;
      planeGeo.vertices[i].z = Math.sin(( i + count * gridWaveHeight)) * (planeGeo.vertices[i]._myZ - (planeGeo.vertices[i]._myZ * gridWaveSpeed))
      plane.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
      count += gridInterlop
    }

    obj.rotation.x += 0.0004;
    obj.rotation.y += 0.0006;
    obj.rotation.z += Math.random() * 0.0005;

    renderer.setViewport(0,0,window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.clear();

    renderer.setViewport(window.innerWidth/2,0,window.innerWidth/2, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.render(sceneTop, camera, 0, false);
    
    renderer.setViewport(0,0,window.innerWidth/2, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.render(scene2, camera2, 0, false);
    
    requestAnimationFrame(myrender);
  }

  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, true);

  function onWindowResize() {
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / 2 / window.innerHeight; 
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    camera2.aspect = window.innerWidth / 2 / window.innerHeight; 
    camera2.updateProjectionMatrix();
};

myrender();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/99/three.min.js"></script>
```